# Round based on number of digits

Tags: arithmetic

I am not a mathematician, but a programmer. My task is to round integers as follows:

```
12 → 12
115 → 120
1115 → 1100
11115 → 11000
```

So you see only the first two digits are precise - the others are just filled with zeroes after rounding the first 3 digits. No problem for a programmer - but I would prefer a simple formula instead of a function which strips characters.

Comment: How would you write this, as a programmer ?

Comment: I would take the first 3 digits, divide them by 10 and round them to integer. Based on the original value I would fill up the rest of the positions with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale the first three digits and divide by $10$ (= scale the first two digits),

$$\frac{v}{10^{\lfloor\log_{10}v\rfloor-1}},$$

round to integer,

$$\left\lfloor\frac{v}{10^{\lfloor\log_{10}v\rfloor-1}}
+0.5\right\rfloor,$$

fill with zeroes,

$$\left\lfloor\frac{v}{10^{\lfloor\log_{10}v\rfloor-1}}
+0.5\right\rfloor10^{\lfloor\log_{10}v\rfloor-1}.$$

E.g. $115\to11.5\to12\to120$, $1115\to11.15\to11\to1100$.

More compactly,

$$[vs^{-1}] s$$ where $s$ is the scaling factor $10^{\lfloor \log_{10}v\rfloor-1}$ and the angle brackets denote rounding.

Comment: Wow - this is really coooool! Thank you